# Update an email with ContactsContract when the contact doesn't have

Tags: java, android, contactscontract

I want to update the mail address of a contact, it seem working but I the case who the contact have not a mail address it's not working and I have this error :

```
#################################################################
W/System.err: Error Code : 0 (SQLITE_OK)
W/System.err: Caused By : unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
#################################################################
```

This is my function `updateMail()` :

```
public static boolean updateMail(Context context, String id, String email){
        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? " + "AND "
                        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?"
                , new String[]{id,
                        String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)});
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, email);
        ops.add(builder.build());

        return (applyBatch(context, ops));
    }
```

Maybe I have to make an insert and not an update when the contact doesn't have mail address, what do you think ?

**EDIT :**

I try this but it's not working... Maybe I don't make a correct selection using the insert :

```
public static boolean updateMail(Context context, String id, String email){
        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder;
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

        if (getMailById(context, id).isEmpty()){

            builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);

            builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Integer.valueOf(id));
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, email);
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME);
            ops.add(builder.build());

        } else {

            builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);

            builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? " + "AND "
                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?"
                    , new String[]{id,
                            String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)});
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, email);
            ops.add(builder.build());

        }

        return (applyBatch(context, ops));
    }
```

Comment: *Maybe I have to make an insert and not an update when the contact doesn't have mail address* - yes, I would guess you should check there is a value first, then use an `insert` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks but it still not working. I edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I have to use `ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID` :

```
public static boolean updateMail(Context context, String id, String email){
        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder;
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

        if (getMailById(context, id).isEmpty()){
            builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, getRawId(context, Long.parseLong(id)));
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, email);
            ops.add(builder.build());
        } else {
            builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);

            builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? " + "AND "
                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?"
                    , new String[]{id,
                            String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)});
            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, email);
            ops.add(builder.build());

        }

        return (applyBatch(context, ops));
    }
```

And the method `getRawId()` :

```
private static long getRawId(Context context, long contactId) {
        String selection = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "='" + contactId + "'";
        try (Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID}, selection, null, null)) {
            assert cur != null;
            if (cur.moveToNext()) { return cur.getLong(0);}
        }
        return 0;
    }
```